# Parsing Non linear packet payload in TC BPF programs

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

We are parsing DHCP packets in TC egress BPF program, In our case, the packet after the UDP header was not present in between skb->data and skb->data_end. On further investigation we found that it lies in non-linear portion. and we have bpf_skb_pull_data(skb,len) to direct access non-linear data.

Few questions based on above:

1. After call to bpf_skb_pull_data(skb, skb->len); the value of  skb->data and skb->data_end pointers changed. Can there be any implication down the stack with change in value of skb->data pointer. Also is this helper function analogous to skb_pull which changes the skb->data pointer and is typically moved when the packet goes up the stack as a result of packet being parsed on that layer? Do we have something similar to skb_linearize() in BPF or any other way to parse non-linear portion?
2. For our case, packet after the UDP header was in non-linear portion, can it happen that packet after IP header go in non-linear or packet after ethernet-header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After call to bpf_skb_pull_data(skb, skb->len); the value of skb->data and skb->data_end pointers changed. Can there be any implication down the stack with change in value of skb->data pointer.

`bpf_skb_pull_data` ends up calling `pskb_expand_head` in the kernel, which clarifies the impact:

> Expands (or creates identical copy, if @nhead and @ntail are zero) header of @skb. [...] All the pointers pointing into skb header may change and must be reloaded after call to this function.

It is therefore expected that the `data` and `data_end` pointers are updated. I can't think of any other implication if you are only consuming the kernel's API (and not making changes to the kernel itself).

---

> Also is this helper function analogous to skb_pull which changes the skb->data pointer

Not really. `skb_pull` removes data from the start of the packet's memory buffer. `bpf_skb_pull_data` pulls in non-linear data when you want to perform a direct packet access with BPF.

---

> Do we have something similar to skb_linearize() in BPF or any other way to parse non-linear portion?

As far as I know, the closest is `bpf_skb_pull_data`. If that helper doesn't address your use case for some reason, I would suggest asking on the BPF mailing list.

---

> For our case, packet after the UDP header was in non-linear portion, can it happen that packet after IP header go in non-linear or packet after ethernet-header?

Yes for the IP payload; It's just a matter of how large your IP header is. It seems unlikely for the Ethernet header.